# C# - SQLite update query not working properly

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'll start this question saying that I know this is not the best way of using SQLite statements but it's easier for me when learning. Here's part of my code:

```
int horas1, minutos1, segundos1, horas2, minutos2, segundos2;
pausaString = "No";
TimeSpan ts = turriStopWatch.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
string sql = "select tiempoPausado from Registros where pausado = 'SI' and enCurso = 'SI' and operacion = '" + operacionString + "' and operador = '" + operadorString + "'";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conexion);
using (SQLiteDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
      if (reader2.Read())
      {
         string tiempoGuardado = reader2.GetString(0);

         horas1 = Convert.ToInt16(tiempoGuardado.Substring(0, 2));
         minutos1 = Convert.ToInt16(tiempoGuardado.Substring(3, 2));
         segundos1 = Convert.ToInt16(tiempoGuardado.Substring(6, 2));

         horas2 = Convert.ToInt16(elapsedTime.Substring(0, 2));
         minutos2 = Convert.ToInt16(elapsedTime.Substring(3, 2));
         segundos2 = Convert.ToInt16(elapsedTime.Substring(6, 2));
         //MessageBox.Show(horas2 + ";" + minutos2 + ";" + segundos2, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

         int sumaHoras = horas1 + horas2;
         int sumaMinutos = minutos1 + minutos2;
         int sumaSegundos = segundos1 + segundos2;

         while (sumaSegundos >= 60) 
         {
            sumaMinutos = sumaMinutos + 1;
            sumaSegundos = sumaSegundos - 60;
         }
         while (sumaMinutos >= 60) 
         {
            sumaHoras = sumaHoras + 1;
            sumaMinutos = sumaMinutos - 60;
         }

         string horarioAGuardar = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", sumaHoras, sumaMinutos, sumaSegundos);

         //MessageBox.Show(horarioAGuardar, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

         sql = "update Registros set tiempoPausado = '" + horarioAGuardar + "' AND pausado = 'NO' where enCurso = 'SI' AND operador = '" + operadorString + "' AND operacion = '" + operacionString + "'";
         command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conexion);
         int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show(rows.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }

      else
      {

      }

}
```

The hour calculation is working fine but, let's suppose tiempoAGuardar is "00:00:02", what I get in tiempoPausado from my database is "0" and pausado is not changed to 'NO'. Even though I change tiempoAGuardar with "asd" it stores 0 at the database. Please help, I've been trying to figure this out for days. Thanks

Comment: The syntax of the update-statement seems off, you do: `UPDATE x SET a=b, k=l` not: `UPDATE x SET a=b AND k=l`, notice I use a comma and not `AND` between the two columns to update. Can you verify that you get no exceptions from this? Do you have a try/catch around it that we're not seeing?

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen !!! It work when I changed AND with a comma. I don't understand why but now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Most likely it was parsed as an expression, `AND pausado = 'NO'` examines `pausado` and evaluates to `true` or `false` based on that, and then that is *AND*ed together with the value you want to store into the first field. In short, you had this: `et tiempoPausado = ('" + horarioAGuardar + "' AND pausado = 'NO')` It is only a conjecture though, have no idea if that is how it was parsed, but good that it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your `UPDATE` statement is wrong.

You have this:

```
"update Registros set tiempoPausado = '" + horarioAGuardar + "' AND pausado = 'NO'
```

You need to replace `AND` with a comma to this:

```
"update Registros set tiempoPausado = '" + horarioAGuardar + "', pausado = 'NO'
```

Most likely the `AND pausado = 'NO'` is parsed as part of an expression that will be evaluated to form the final value for `tiempoPausado`.